# Basic vuex example not commiting

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

I am trying to get vuex to manage the reactivity of authentication for users, and I just cannot get it to work. Since nothing I am doing is working I decided to scrap it and try a basic example with a button to set a boolean value to true, to see if the problem was my code or with something else interfering or something. Even this basic example I tried is not working. However, when I tried it in a code sandbox it worked perfectly fine [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-meadow-bykvm?file=/src/main.js). I have come to the conclusion that my something else is messing with veux.

There is a lot of code so I put it inside pastebin

[Store/index.js](https://pastebin.com/qQJzC9NR)

```
In pastebin
```

[App.vue](https://pastebin.com/N8gAJwVK)

```
In pastebin
```

Comment: Damn, a lot of code. Did you tried to debug it thanks to the Vuex tab ?

Comment: What veux tab. And I'm sorry for the amount of code.

Comment: This one: https://imgur.com/rgeR2gX

Comment: I dont have that tab, not anywhere I know of anyways

Comment: Do you have vue devtools installed ? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/nhdogjmejiglipccpnnnanhbledajbpd?hl=en

Comment: I've installed it and the tabs still isnt there

Comment: Toggle off and back your devtools.

Comment: Yea did that still not there. Seems it doesnt work with vue cli

Comment: Totally does. Kill your server, close the tab, run your server again, open a new tab, toggle the devtools. Also, if you're using Vue3, it's another version of the devtools, here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vuejs-devtools/ljjemllljcmogpfapbkkighbhhppjdbg?hl=en You can totally install both of them at the same time.

Comment: Its showing up now, I was using vue 3 so it was probs the old extension that was the issue

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I cooked up my installation. I uninstalled and then reinstalled (make sure it is in the correct location) and my reactivity issue was solved. Given I installed vuex 4 beta as the stable version was not released. I have come to the conclusion that there was a bug in the installation